# Connected Component Cleaning cv2.arcLength OpenCv: Assertion Failed

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to implement Connected Component noise removal, in OpencCV 2.3.4 Python API, as outlined starting from page 287 in [Learning OpenCV](http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/vision/dipakmj/papers/OReilly%20Learning%20OpenCV.pdf)

I have got as far as computing the lengths of the contours, in which I get a cryptic assertion error.

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (curve.checkVector(2) >= 0 && (curve.depth() == CV_32F || curve.depth() == CV_32S)) in unknown function, file ..\..\..\OpenCV-2.4.3\modules\imgproc\src\contours.cpp, line 1886
```

Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
import cPickle

CVCONTOUR_APPROX_LEVEL = 2
CVCLOSE_ITR = 1

def main():
    mask = cv2.imread('input.jpg', cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
    findConnectedComponents(mask)

def findConnectedComponents(mask,
                            poly1Hull0 = 1,
                            perimScale = 4,
                            num = None,
                            bbs = None,
                            centers = None):
    cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, np.array(0), iterations=CVCLOSE_ITR)
    cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, np.array(0), iterations=CVCLOSE_ITR)

    contours = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    #the Pickle trick solves some strange type errors
    tmp = cPickle.dumps(contours)    
    contours = cPickle.loads(tmp)

    for contour in contours:
        perimeter = cv2.arcLength(np.array(contour), True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    print 'done'
```

Any ideas what the error means and how I could get around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - `cv2.findContours()` provides you two outputs, **contours and hierarchy**. You specified only contours. So change line as follows (this is the main error) :

```
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

2 - `contours` is a list of numpy arrays. Each array is a contour. So when you pass contour to `cv2.arcLength()` you need not make it again a numpy array. (it is not an error, but unnecessary operation), So change that line as follows :

```
   for contour in contours:
        perimeter = cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
```

Now try your code and check if it works !!!

For more details on contour operations on OpenCV, **[visit here.](http://opencvpython.blogspot.com/2012/06/hi-this-article-is-tutorial-which-try.html)**

Comment: Wow! It worked! I had no idea putting variables for multiple return types would have an effect on the output. And I was actually already using your blog as a guide. (you probably know their's a drought of cv2 examples) So thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I know, I would like to add more samples, but my academics doesn't give me much free time. Anyway I am glad it worked !!!